# Wäre gebrannt wurde / hätte gebrannt

Tags: grammaticality

Können Sie mir sagen, welcher Satz gebräuchlich ist? Soweit ich das verstehe, ist beides verständlich, aber ich möchte wissen, welcher gebräuchlicher ist.

1. Hätte ich nicht vergessen, einen Timer einzustellen, wäre mein Buchweizen nicht angebrannt worden.
2. Hätte ich nicht vergessen, einen Timer einzustellen, hätte mein Buchweizen nicht angebrannt.

Comment: I recommend to check references as  [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:anbrennen) before inventing new forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keiner davon ist korrekt. Richtig wäre:

> Hätte ich nicht vergessen, einen Timer einzustellen, wäre mein Buchweizen nicht angebrannt.

Das Verb ist *anbrennen*, und es bildet zusammengesetzte Formen mit *sein*.

Etwas brennt an.

Etwas ist angebrannt.